# Scientific tick numbers with space as thousands separator in matplotlib

Tags: python, matplotlib

I want to have ticks on the y-axis formatted the following way:

- numbers < 1M should be written out, with spaces as thousands separator (e.g. `20 000`)
- numbers > 1M should be in scientific notation, just as the Scalar formatter does (`2.0` with `x10^6` above the axis).

Now, I can achieve both of these functionalities *seperataly*.

```
matplotlib.ticker.FuncFormatter(lambda x, p: format(x, ',').replace(',', ' '))
```

replaces thousands separator with space.

```
formatter = matplotlib.ticker.ScalarFormatter()
formatter.set_powerlimits((-4, 6))
```

gives scientific notation for 1M+.

I guess I have to set a ScalarFormatter and slightly change one of its functions, or I have to write above the y-axis with the FuncFormatter. However, I could not find how to do that.

#### EDIT

I slightly came closer to my goal. By using `format(x, ',.6g').replace(',', ' ')` I at least have the desired number formats.
Nevertheless, I'd prefer to have the exponential notation *above* the axis, and for all of my ticks, if the largest grows too large...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In principle you could just `set_useLocale(True)` for the scalar formatter and use a modified locale. ScalarFormatter doesn't, however, use groupings (see [source](https://github.com/matplotlib/matplotlib/blob/560ccffce3200c6713e7d29beee6aaf382c53adc/lib/matplotlib/ticker.py#L650)), so we must derive our own ScalarFormatter and set `grouping=True`).

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from matplotlib.ticker import ScalarFormatter
import locale

fig, (ax1, ax2) = plt.subplots(ncols=2)

ax1.set_ylim(1, 10_000)
ax2.set_ylim(1, 10_000_000)


class MyScalarFormatter(ScalarFormatter):
    def __call__(self, x, pos=None):
        if len(self.locs) == 0:
            return ''
        else:
            xp = (x - self.offset) / (10. ** self.orderOfMagnitude)
            if abs(xp) < 1e-8:
                xp = 0
            if self._useLocale:
                s = locale.format_string(self.format, (xp,), grouping=True)
            else:
                s = self.format % xp
            return self.fix_minus(s)

sf = MyScalarFormatter(useLocale=True)
locale._override_localeconv = {'thousands_sep': ' ', 'grouping': [3,0]}

ax1.yaxis.set_major_formatter(sf)
ax2.yaxis.set_major_formatter(sf)

plt.show()
```

[image]

Comment: Seems great. But it somehow does not take the grouping into account. I debugged your function, the `__call__` returns the expected format, but somehow the final plot has spaces in the labeling.
I tried your mwe, same result.

Comment: Dang it. I found it, i had `text.usetex` set. This somehow brakes setting the space as separator. Using `\,` as a thin space solved it. Thanks for your work, it was the main part though :D

Comment: glad you could make it work, I could only now try and look into it but you already found the reason.